# Validation Rule on Account get fired when creating Opportunity

Tags: validation-rule

This is my validation rule for Account.But when I create new Opportunity in Account tab it throw me this error .

> 'Validation Formula 'myAccount_rule' invalid Could not access the
>   following field BillingAddress.'

I didnot change anything on Account field but I just create new Opportunity in the Account type.Here is my validation rule formula:

```
AND(NOT(ISCHANGED(Type)) ,ISPICKVAL(Type,'Customer'),ISCHANGED(BillingAddress),$Profile.Name <> 'Finance',  $Profile.Name <> 'Operations', 
$Profile.Name <> 'System Administrator')
```

Why this happening and how to solve it?

Comment: may be there is some trigger on opportunity updating account. check that.

Comment: Might also be a process or roll-up summary field.

Comment: what do you mean by roll-up summary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that BillingAddress is a compound field and doesn't (yet) successfully support the `ISCHANGED` function. Curiously, it compiles fine in the VR editor.

You'll need to test each field explicitly

```
... OR(ISCHANGED(BillingStreet),ISCHANGED(BillingCity),....) ...
```

this was [addressed also in the SFDC Forum](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000Cxl0AAC)

Comment: Addition- it is also read only field.